# Find the probability that the other urn contains exactly $k$ stones

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Suppose we have a two large urns. Each urn has $N$ stones inside it. We randomly select one of the urns, and remove a stone from the selected urn. We repeat this process until we select a urn that has no stones. At this point, what is the probability that the other urn has exactly $k$ stones$?$

How  to approach this question$?$ The probability of selecting any urn is $\frac12.$ Since this problem seems to be extra complicated, lets try for some simple cases. For $k=0$ it is not possible. For $k=1$ the only possible way is to select each urn alternatively till the last. For $k=2$ I have no idea. But I just realized for $k=1$ can't we have an another case where a person randomly selects the same urn until it is left with $1$ stone and then randomly select the other urn till it contains $0$ stones$?$ I am thinking about more incomplete steps. But I'm also finding it hard to find the probability in each case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the [Banach Matchbox Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%27s_matchbox_problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can view it as a match where each has a Pr of $\frac12$ of winning a game, and that player $A$, (say) has won $N$ games while  player $B$ has won $N-k$ games, and vice-versa.(Later we can double the probability)

To me it looks like a *conditional* probability question, eg for player $A$, P(Player $A$ has won **exactly** $N$ in $2N-k$ games | Player A has won)

P(Player A has won in exactly $(2N-k)$ games)

$$ {\dbinom{2N-k}N\binom{2N-k}{N-k}\over 2^{2N-k}}= U$$

P(Player A has won)
$$= \binom{2N-k}N *\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}{\dbinom{2N-k}{N-j}\over 2^{2N-j}} = V$$

And lastly the desired conditional probability multiplying by two by symmetry for $B$, too, winning
$$= 2U/V$$